# Xcode/iOS App freezing, how to track such errors

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have sometimes app freezing I do not know what is the source of problem. 
It happens rarely but happens. I consider how to track such issue 
I have crashlytics from firebase but there is no errors as freezing is I suppose something with threads maybe some deadlocks or infinite loops.

Is there way to track such things?
What maybe reasons of app freezing and being inactive (it is SwiftUI app) ?
Are there possibilities to track/profile apps installed on devices (not connected via Xcode) and send informations such that are available in Instrument to something like firebase console or other 3rd party tools.

**Update**

I think I do not indicated important fact.
It freezes UI definitely not for a few seconds but app need do be killed and restarted again.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some heavy process that locks your main thread, so it freezes your UI.

You track the problems, performance, leaks and more using [Instruments](https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/).

There are sample topics:

- [Instruments Tutorial with Swift: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/397-instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started)
- [How to find and fix slow code using Instruments](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/81/how-to-find-and-fix-slow-code-using-instruments)

And WWDC videos like

- [Using Time Profiler in Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/418/)
- [Creating Custom Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/410/)

Comment: Can I track this things without Xcode if app is running on tester code via TestFlight, Firebase Console or other tool.

Comment: It is hard to track without debugging. Monitoring tools tools may help you to see some base metrics. ex: [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon).

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced some of these weird behaviours before. And mostly the reason behind it was a task that is blocking the main thread making it unresponsive. Pause the app and check the stack trace. Also make sure all your UI operations are done on the main thread. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I think it is related to threading and some race condition, main thread deadlock or infinite looping. Problem is it is happening very rarely and in not while debugging in Xcode. Some tester experienced this situation and there I do not have any logs and hints what may go wrong. In SwiftUI there is many refreshes hard to say what can be causing this.

Comment: I would first rule things out one by one. Starting by not performing any process and return hardcoded mocks from my ViewModels.